# How do you return a single column from a eloquent relationship in Laravel 6?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-6

I have model 'Post' which has the columns 'id', 'name', 'content' and 'status'

I have model 'PostStatus' which has the columns 'id' and 'name'

On the Post.php I have the following:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public function status()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\PostStatus','status');
    }
}
```

In a controller elsewhere I have:

```
Post::with('status')->get()->toArray();
```

Which returns an array with all the posts with 'id', 'name' as 'content' as their column values and 'status' as an array of the data from the relevant row in the Post Statuses table. What I want to achieve is the 'status' column being simply the string value of the 'name' column in the PostStatus model rather than an array of the entire row. I've tried using ->select on the status function within the Post model, but this still returns the value as an array. I'd rather avoid using SQL directly to achieve my goal.

In summary I'd like my function in the controller to return:

```
array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["name"]=>
    string(12) "Post Example"
    ["content"]=>
    string(7) "Content"
    ["status"]=>
    string(6) "Active"
  }
```

rather than

```
array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["name"]=>
    string(12) "Post Example"
    ["content"]=>
    string(7) "Content"
    ["status"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(1)
      ["name"]=>
      string(6) "Active"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Not sure but You can use count() on array and loop through this.. Try this and let me know what happens

Answer (score 2):

That's not really how relationships are designed to work, and you may find that you actually need the relationship for something else later on, so overriding it is probably not the best course of action.

You should consider using an accessor to return an attribute (e.g., `$post->status_name`).
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators

```php
class Post extends Model
{
    // append the attribute for serialization
    $appends = ['status_name'];

    // get an attribute named 'status_name'
    public function getStatusNameAttribute()
    {
        return $this->status->name ?? '';
    }

    public function status()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\PostStatus','status');
    }
}
```

Note: If you plan to do this, it would be wise to still use `with('status')` when getting posts as it will prevent Laravel from running a separate query for each label.  You may even want to apply this as a global scope in the boot method of your Post model, so you don't have to do it every time.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#global-scopes